# Full UEFI System, Grub 2 self-compiled + Clover 2, Debian kFreeBSD installation?

Tags: debian, kernel, usb, uefi, debian-installer

I've a computer with full installation UEFI system, with 2 bootloaders (GRUB & Clover on ESP) clover is the primary bootloader that allows me to load OSX and grub2. I want to make a new install of Debian wheezy/kFreeBSD, but grub2 cannot execute the command: `kfreebsd`.

**NOTE:** I was using a USB key, and I don't have any CD drive.

#### Questions

- How can I use an ISO of **Debian/kfreebsd-amd64**?
- ***without*** any iso-hybrid for the USB (not available) and ***without*** using grub2-efi (no kfreebsd)?
- would it be possible to install from OSX/Unix?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i've found the solution !
Use an Virtual Machine with GNU/kFreeBSD and login as root.

Edit ***/etc/apt/sources.list*** like this :

```
deb http:[COUNTRY MIRROR].debian.org/debian stable main non-free contrib
deb http:[COUNTRY MIRROR].debian.org/debian testing main non-free contrib
deb http:[COUNTRY MIRROR].debian.org/debian unstable main non-free contrib
```

And create or modify ***/etc/apt/preferences*** like this:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 700
Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 650
Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 600
```

Update your sources, after install this :

- **apt-get install bison m4 autogen autoconf help2man libopts25-dev flex
  libfont-freetype-perl automake autotools-dev libfreetype6-dev texinfo**
- [The latest grub archive.](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grub/) (extract and enter in)

```
export EFI_ARCH=i386 or EFI_ARCH=x86_64
./configure --with-platform=efi --target=${EFI_ARCH} --program-prefix="" --disable-grub-mkfont
make
```

If you have an error with stdio.h, edit the file ***grub-core/gnulib/stdio.h*** at the error (line 456 for me), fix it like [this patch](https://dev.openwrt.org/attachment/ticket/12005/stdio.patch) (lines 7 and 9) and **redo a make**.
**If that not work again :**

```
make clean
./configure --with-platform=efi --target=${EFI_ARCH} --program-prefix="" --disable-grub-mkfont --disable-werror
make
```

### After compilation

```
cd grub-core/
../grub-mkimage -O ${EFI_ARCH}-efi -d . -o grub.efi -p "" part_bsd part_gpt part_msdos ntfs ntfscomp hfsplus fat ext2 normal chain boot configfile linux bsd multiboot
cp grub.efi *.mod *.lst [EFI SYSTEM FOLDER]/grub/
```